# typescript calling statement after all the function statements are accomplished

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a long function that is getting data from a database at several levels.

```
  getResult() {
    this.appService
      .getCountries()
      .subscribe(
        (countries: Country[]) => {
          this.countries = countries;
        },
        () => {},
        () => {
          for (let country of this.countries) {
            let cities: City[] = [];
            this.appService
              .getCities(country.id.toString())
              .subscribe(
                (theCities: Cities[]) => {
                  cities = theCities;
                },
                () => {},
                () => {
                  for (let city of cities) {
                    if (city.population>1000) {
                      console.log(city);
                    }
                  }
                }
              );
          }
        }
      );
    this.result = true;
  }
```

Once everything is done, I want to the statement

```
this.result = true;
```

to be called. However, it is called before the above code finishes.

Even if placed at the end of the `onCompleted` function it, the

```
this.result = true;
```

is being called before the loop is accomplished.

Comment: The three callbacks provided to `subscribe` are `onNext`, `onError`, and `onCompleted`. Is there a reason you don't want to put `this.result = true;` at the end of the `onError` and `onCompleted` callbacks?

Comment: First of all, API is badly written. Ask your back-end developer to send list of countries where each country has list of cities. For now, move your `this.result = true;` code to the end of outer `for` loop.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I placed `this.result = true;` at the end of the `onCompleted`, but it is executing before the end of the for loop. I tested that!

Comment: @LiterallyIlliterate I placed it at the end of the outer loop, but it is executing before the end of the for loop. It only works if I place it inside a timeout function.

Comment: @EddyG: Okay, now that I'm looking through your code again, I see that you've got subscriptions inside of subscriptions, which is generally something you want to avoid. You _could_ use `flatMap` to flatten out your Observables into a single Observable so you can put `this.result = true;` at the end of its subscription. But based on what I can guess from the code you've posted, I think you'll find it simpler to use `.toPromise()` after each call, and switch to an `async`/`await` pattern, where you can use the `for` loops and other imperative constructs you're used to.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior can you please provide the solution?

Comment: No promises on whether it'll compile or run, but the answer I posted should give you the general idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find it simpler to use .toPromise() after each call, and switch to an async/await pattern, where you can use the for loops and other imperative constructs you're used to.

```
  async getResult() {
    this.countries = await this.appService.getCountries().toPromise();
    for (let country of this.countries) {
      const cities: City[] = await this.appService
        .getCities(country.id.toString())
        .toPromise();
      for (let city of cities) {
        if (city.population>1000) {
          console.log(city);
        }
      }
    this.result = true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think, if you dont you want to change your code, you could use a counter.

```
getResult() {
    let count; // here a change
    this.appService
      .getCountries()
      .subscribe(
        (countries: Country[]) => {
          this.countries = countries;
          this.count = this.countries.lent // here a change
        },
        () => {},
        () => {
          for (let country of this.countries) {
            let cities: City[] = [];
            this.appService
              .getCities(country.id.toString())
              .subscribe(
                (theCities: Cities[]) => {
                 count-- // here a change
                  cities = theCities;
                },
                () => {},
                () => {
                  for (let city of cities) {
                    if (city.population>1000) {
                      console.log(city);
                    }
                  }
                 if(count===0)this.result = true // here a change
                }
              );
          }
        }
      );
    // this.result = true;
  }
```